# How to manipulate attributes of url-less dropdown item in a the custom wordpress menu?

Tags: menus, css

I need to change the color of some custom link elements in dropdown of my wordpress custom menu [here](http://www.ventcleaningnj.com/residential-air-duct-cleaning-nj/). There 3 items in my dropdown that dont have any url associated with them:

- Air Duct
- Chimney
- Dryer Vent

They will be just the headers for other dropdown items below them.

I need to be able to change their attributes such color, font-family and size, etc.

I was trying to create menu-item-type-custom and menu-item-object-custom and even menu-item-#### classes, but it didn't do it... :( Please help!

Comment: Why use CMs for this?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I need to create a drop down like here - http://bit.ly/okHDHb (look under Services)

Comment: I see, so those items act like headers for a group of menu items

Comment: yes exactly. What is the best way to achieve this? I need to be ablo to style just those headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the `CSS Classes` (Screen Setting -> Flag CSS Classes) and use it to customize every menu item that you want to be styled in a different manner.

You must use a Custom menu, of course.

Comment: I've created class "gh" :   .gh {color: red;}  
.gh A:link {text-decoration: none; color:red;}  
.gh A:visited {text-decoration: none; color:red;}  
.gh A:active {text-decoration: none; color:red;}  
.gh A:hover {text-decoration: none; color: red;} , But for some reason it still showing regular dropdown style. Is there any special css that I have to use for that class?

Comment: Is it possible it gets overriden by ul ul li class?

Comment: The class is applied to list items, so use it like `li.gh a{color:red;}` and so on. Some pseudo classes may not taken into consideration because the item is an anchor.

Comment: Right now I have this in my style.css : .gh {color: red;}
.gh a{color:red;} .gh a:hover {color:red;} . I can see with my developer tools that the style applied to the item, however still no change in appearance.. I see there are some other class applied as well, maybe they override gh class?

Comment: could be.. try `#top-menu ul li.gh a{color:red;}`

Comment: that did it!! man you my hero!

Comment: I would up your answer too, but rep still too low :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using a filter if you want to do this programmatically:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', function($classes, $item, $args){

  if(empty($item->url))
    $classes[] = 'your-header-class';

  return $classes;

}, 10, 3);
```

But you should go with keatch's solution :)

Comment: yeah, I was just reading about wp_nav_menu_items hook before I started this thread.. You're right, I really hope to make the custom menu css classes to work

Comment: anyway, where should I add your filter, in what file?